# ¿Como puedo concatenar cadenas en una validacion V-bind?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo una validación de Vue.js que hace obligatorio ciertos campos segun el valor  que tenga un `<el-option>` que muestra distintos `estados_civiles` y necesito que los campos sean obligatorios cuando el valor es distinto de `'viudo','separado','soltero'`

he aquí mi codigo que solo valida soltero en este caso

```
 v-bind:required="this.form.civil_state !='Soltero' ? true : false"
```

ademas necesito mostrar el mensaje correspondiente por que por defecto muesta `cuple_name_is required`, alguna idea?

esta es mi propiedad, pero se ve que no está entrando ahi

```
couple_name:[
        { message: this.$t('error_msg.couple_name_required')},
      ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentalo asi:

```
v-bind:required="(this.form.civil_state !='Soltero' 
                    && this.form.civil_state != 'Viudo' 
                      && this.form.civil_state != 'Separado') ? true : false"
```

Comment: no seria mejor llamar a una funcion que verifique los valores y devuelva true o false? esto no esta mal, pero se va complicando....

Comment: o por ahi una computada?

Comment: Cualquiera de las tres opciones esta bien.  Yo uso cada una dependiendo del caso.  Si es algo que se va a chequear una sola vez, uso algo como esto.  Pero si tienes que chequear en diferentes lugares, una de las otras dos opciones seria mejor.

Comment: Si si.. que quede claro que esto es correcto y que solo pensaba en limpiar un poco el codigo.. sobre todo si tiene que validar 6 o 7...

Comment: tambien pense eso, que una funcion valide todos los el-form-item por que tengo 4 en total

Comment: La forma en que estas validando es correcta, la funcion seria solo si tienes que hacer la misma validacion en diferentes lugares.

Comment: y si hago la funcion como la implemento ? v-bind:required=civilState()  ?

Comment: Correcto, tienes que retornar un valor booleano.